# odoo 10 QWEB report how to pass value that is used in methods in parser?

Tags: html, report, odoo-10, qweb

I have a model that saves reports in binary fields for archiving. To do that I use the pdf_get().

```
document = self.env['report'].sudo().get_pdf(ids, report_name)
```

The problem is when I want to create a report that doesn't use the models fields but has to compute values from related models with the model that is pass with ids.

My report model

```
class ReportHistory(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'report.hr.report_history'


    def _get_report(self, ids[0]):
        record = self.env['hr.history'].search([('id', '=', ids[0])])
        return record



    def _get_company(self, ids):
        rec = self._get_report(ids)
        if len(rec) > 0:
            return rec[0].company_name
```

My biggest problem is that I can't debug so I can't what data is passed. The print or logger or raise ValidationError won't work. Probably due to running odoo on windows pc.
Every answer that I found it was said to pass values to report like this but it doesn't work.

```
@api.model
def render_html(self, docids, data=None):

    docargs = 
        'doc_ids': self.ids,
        'doc_model': self.model,
        'data': data,
        'company': self._get_company,
    }
    return self.env['report'].render()
```

So how to correctly pass values from methods to report? Or did I only do a dumb mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return self.env['report'].render(report_name, docargs)
```

Comment: Please explain why this code works, not just posting the code itself.

Comment: I forgot to add the method parameters in my example. So really your answer isn't  helpful. But I figured it out, the ids parameter that is passed to render_html method as the first parameter(docids). So I could search for all the data in related models by those docids and then pass it in the docargs dict..